# Why can't I see the created database file in my working directory (Flask)?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Problem: I am new to creating a website on the flask and my code is running smoothly without any error, but I can't see the database file on my working directory or in my Project and I dont know what is the reason why the database file is not showing or creating in my directory. Can someone help me?

## My directory

```
Project
|
|__flask-session
|__ST_website
   |____flask-session
   |____static
   |____templates
   |______ __init__.py
   |______ database.py
   |______ primary.py
   |______ user_identification.py
|__venv(library root)
|__run.py
(|__ST_database.db # wanted to create)
```

### **init**.py

```
import os
from flask_session import Session
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager
from datetime import timedelta

# Database
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "ST_database.db"
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'ST_website/static/csv-files'  # Upload Folder


def create_app():
    """ Creating an App"""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hi'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite:///ST_database.db'
    app.config["SQLAlCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False  # Handling Warnings
    app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=20)  # How long will the data last.
    db.init_app(app)
    Session(app)

    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER  # Upload file

    #      file name       Variable name
    from .primary import primary
    from .user_identification import user_identi

    # Registering Blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(user_identi, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(primary, url_prefix='/')

    login_man = LoginManager()
    login_man.login_view = 'user_identi.login'  # Directing here if the user is not log-in
    login_man.init_app(app)  # telling Login manager what app will use

    from .database import User, UserData
    create_database(app)

    @login_man.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        """Load the user"""
        return User.query.get(int(id))  # automatically get the Primary Key

    return app


def create_database(application):
    db_filename = f'ST_website/{DB_NAME}'
    if not os.path.exists(db_filename):
        db.create_all(app=application)
        print('Created Database!')
```

### database.py

```
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    user_data = db.relationship('UserData')


class UserData(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150))
    filename = db.Column(db.String(150))
    filepath = db.Column(db.String(150))
    date_of_upload = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

### run.py

```
from ST_website import create_app
app = create_app()
print(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

### Terminal

```
D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872:FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(

Created Database!
<Flask 'ST_website'>
 * Serving Flask app 'ST_website' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
* Restarting with stat
D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:851: UserWarning: Neither SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI nor SQLALCHEMY_BINDS is set. Defaulting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI to "sqlite:///:memory:".
  warnings.warn(
D:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py:872:FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 412-312-823
Created Database!
<Flask 'ST_website'>
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.1.10:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Comment: Your code is trying to create `DB_NAME+'.db'` in the folder `ST_website`.  That's not what you show at the top.  And I don't see `DB_NAME` defined anywhere.

Comment: don't you get error message when you run code in console/terminal ?

Comment: where do you run `create_app()`? You could also use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. Maybe you never runs code which should create database. Or you have wrong value in variable when you create database and you create it in different place.

Comment: I am sorry for the incomplete information. I updated the code and added the DB_NAME variable and I tried to print the create_app(). Still the can't see the database file

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Tim Roberts  and Sir. Furas. I found a solution to my problem.  
Wrong: app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL'] .
Correct: app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] .

Answer (score 0):

In your **init**.py file, please change this line.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL'] = 'sqlite:///ST_database.db'
```

to,

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///ST_database.db'
```

Comment: When answering, it is always good practice to explain in text the solution and not code-only lines.